# If I have been swallowed by a Froghemoth and it is hit by fireball, do I take damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, area-of-effect

If I have been swallowed by a Froghemoth and it is hit by *fireball*, do I take damage?

The question is very similar to [Is a Mummy still inside its sarcophagus affected by a fireball hitting right over it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88343/is-a-mummy-still-inside-its-sarcophagus-affected-by-a-fireball-hitting-right-ove), but the answer given really isn't that clear and there are several creatures that swallow like the Froghemoth does. It would be good to have a ruling for how much cover being swallowed gives you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This isn't directly from the Froghemoth, but I think the wording on most Swallow abilities is more or less the same, so I'm using the Giant Frog as an example:

> ***Swallow.*** The frog makes one bite attack against a Small or smaller target it is grappling. If the attack hits, the target is swallowed, and the grapple ends. *The swallowed target is blinded and restrained, it has total cover against attacks and other effects outside the frog*, and it takes 5 (2d4) acid damage at the start of each of the frog's turns. The frog can have only one target swallowed at a time.

The emphasis is mine. The swallowed creature should have total cover against anything going on outside the frog, including being immune to Fireball.

Comment: Why would total cover protect you from fireball.  The description of total cover specially says *A target with total cover can't be targeted directly by an attack or a spell, although some spells can reach such a target by including it in an area of effect.*.  I read that to say specifically total cover does not protect you from AOE effects if you are in the area of effect.

Comment: I assume creatures with total cover have the same benefit as half-cover if they're within the AoE. Half-cover states: "A target with three-quarters cover has a +5 bonus to AC and Dexterity saving throws."

Comment: @SteveBauer this might have to be a separate question, but Total Cover protects you from area spells -> A spell’s effect expands in straight lines from the point of origin. If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of origin to a location within the area of effect, that location isn’t included in the spell’s area. To block one of these imaginary lines, an obstruction must provide total cover.

Comment: @Erik I just reread that and you are correct.  Fireball has the odd passage that it spreads around corners which seems to modify the normal AOE rules but I will ask that in a separate question, no corners to round inside a creatures stomach.

Comment: How fireball works around corners is answered here:


 https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93050/does-a-fireball-ignore-total-cover

Comment: If the frog had its mouth open, perhaps the around the corner rule applies...lol.

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars - While you lol'ed at the end, you're correct. That's exactly how fireball works. If the frogs mouth is closed, the target can not be reached by the fireball. If the mouth is open, the flames can reach the target and it is affected. This is due to fireball's ability to fill it's AoE by flowing around corners, and it's duration of instant means the flow is at the speed of it being cast.

Answer (score 7):

### Fireball ignores total cover as long as there is a corner within reach of the spell

Fireball:

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range and then blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame. Each creature in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw. A target takes 8d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. **The fire spreads around corners**. It ignites flammable objects in the area that aren’t being worn or carried.

And this is the area of effect rulling:

> A spell’s Effect expands in straight lines from the point of Origin. If no unblocked straight line extends from the point of Origin to a Location within the area of Effect, that Location isn’t included in the spell’s area. To block one of these imaginary lines, an obstruction must provide total cover.

The fireball text allow it to circunvent some limitations of an area of effect spell, as long as there is a corner to expand. So a target behind a wall with a corner within the radius of fireball will still be affected. If there are no corners (the character is inside a locked building, for example) the fireball area of effect will not include past the cover.

Froghemoth bite action:

> Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +10 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 28 (4d10 + 6) piercing damage and the target is swallowed if it is a Medium or smaller creature. **A swallowed creature is blinded and restrained, has total cover against attacks and other effects outside the froghemoth**

While inside the froghemoth, the character has total cover against anything outside the froghemoth itself. The froghmetoh is all around that creature, there are no corners to expand here. The fireball does not affect the swallowed creature.